# Monitor how a site will interact with internal javascript in different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

Im going to write a javascript library as browser:

In all browsers (ex Safari, Firefox, Chrome, IE, …  in desktop and mobile environment), included some standard javascript objects: Window, Navigator, Screen, History, Location, Document, Events, ... with many attributes (or properties) and methods which are different between browsers. And my job is:

create 1 javascript file, run in a specific browser, ex Safari, named this script: "libgen.js". This script collect all javascript objects in browser (exclude HTML tags, even HTML5 tags) with all attributes (or properties) and methods, then generate a javascript can run in phantomjs environment, named new script: "libsim.js".

In "libsim.js", it will simulate all attributes (or properties) and methods of all javascript objects was collected before, then when running "libsim.js" in phantomjs, it will load a specific page (input parameter), call this page is "test page", wait for a specific timeout (input parameter), then stop script

Ex: In Safari, exist an object name: "Obj", with properties and methods as below: 
Properties: 
P1 
P2 
Methods: 
M1() 
M2()

"libgen.js" will run in Safari (put "libgen.js" to a html page, then open this page by Safari) and then collect object "Obj", then generate new script "libsim.js" (output to console or a textarea, then munually save to file "libsim.js") 
when run: phantomjs libsim.js  <120> 
If "testpage.html" call to Obj.M1(), "libsim.js" will catch that, then logout to a file include these information: 
Name of property or method 
timestamp 
then it return the original value 
For detail example, you can review at: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/detectsniff.js 
In original example, it log out to console, in this job, it will log-out to a file, named: "trace.txt"

I want to monitor how a site will interact with internal javascript in different browsers

And my question is: Do you think this job is possible, and do you have any other solution to suggest me, thank you so much

Comment: it could simulate some things, but will miss a lot as well. closures and modules, xbrowser method quirks, limits of using same host on each, etc.

Comment: You would have to implement all the behaviors/methods/properties of all the objects available to javascript and somehow copy the parts of the behaviors that are different in every single browser.  This does not sound practical to me at all.  It might be more useful to you here if you told us what the real problem you're trying to solve and we might be able to offer other, more practical ideas, for how to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

> *[the generated script] "libsim.js" […] will simulate all […] methods of all javascript objects was collected before*
>
> Do you think this job is possible?

No, definitely not. Those methods that you are trying to simulate are *internal*:

- You don't know what they do (as you say, all cross-browser quirks, plus you don't want to implement your own browser in js)
- you don't know their code (they're called *native* for a reason: they might not even be written in JS at all)
- you cannot simply test all possible inputs - and you can't even determine their output, which might be some internal state.

You just cannot "return the original value".

Comment: Actually, someone ported webkit to pure javascript: https://github.com/trevorlinton/webkit.js

Comment: @ArtjomB.: Yeah, I guessed someone would have used emscripten to port a browser engine to js (as has been done with js engines). However, that comes with its own issues and features, and is more like "yet another browser" not an exact replication of Safari (or whichever one OP wants to simulate).